# Почему появляется отступ в мобильной версии сайта?

Tags: html, css

подскажите пожалуйста почему при просмотре сайта на мобильной версии появляются отступы. на декстопе все нормально. даже при ресайзе тоже ни каких глюков, а вот когда открываю и просматриваю сайт на мобильном появляются отступы.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body{ 
background:#ddd;
}

.wraper{
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 0px;
}
.img-class{
 display: inline-block;
 background: green;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">

<div class="img-class"></div>
<div class="img-class"></div>
<div class="img-class"></div>
<div class="img-class"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: А Вы прям на мобильном смотрели? Или через браузер? Если через браузер, то это он так отображает и на самом деле там нету отступов.

Comment: Такое происходит именно уже в мобильной версии, всё дело в `display: inline-block;` замените на `display:flex` или любой другой ваш вариант и полоски исчезнут.

Comment: Смотрел и на мобильном и через браузер. проверял на разных компьютерах, заменил display-inline на display-flex, но все равно проблема осталась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так. Вставь этот фрагмент в css файл. В этом случае контент обновиться, если ширина 411px или меньше.

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 411px) { 
  .img-class{ 
   margin: -1px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. ваш вариант действительно помог, только пришлось выставить размер на 1024 так как если ширина 411 то на других экранах возникает аналогичная проблема. еще раз большое спасибо